# How to hide Particular view in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have to hide Particular views in recyclerview, I am trying to hide some views but view has gone but space is there,I have tried putting heights=0 in cardview but still did not work ,  what I should I do?

This is my XML code list data

```
<layout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res- 
                        auto">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/child_card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2sp"
        app:cardElevation="12sp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/bsp_icon" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/label_value"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lines="2"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

and this is my recyclerview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/list_layout_dashboard_child_view">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

this is my Adapter code

```
if (txnTypeMap.get("CUST_CR") != null &&
    obj.getChildName().equalsIgnoreCase(txnTypeMap.get("CUST_CR"))) {
    binding.childCardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: post some code that you have tried

Comment: please show your java code....

Comment: Just remove the data from the data source of your recycler adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of recycler adapter. That should update your recycler view

Answer (score 1):

important always set this if you are sure your data will change in recyclerview **mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);**

first remove the item from list e.g. list.remove(position which you want to hide)
next call notifyItemChanged(postion) and it should work ->this is better approach than calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

You should hide all views or parent from UsersViewholder layout xml. You should hide entire viewholder or each view

Entire viewholder:

```
itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or each element:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But don't forget to set them VISIBLE otherwise, you will end up with some strange things from recycling

Comment: See this code android:visibility="gone" and in adapter if (txnTypeMap.get("CUST_CR") != null && 
       obj.getChildName().equalsIgnoreCase(txnTypeMap.get("CUST_CR"))) {
            binding.childCardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Without setting `setVisibility` to `View.GONE`, try to remove the the data from the data source and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

This is the more efficient way to hide a view from `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

you have to set visibility gone to view in else case because views are reused in recycler view

```
 if (txnTypeMap.get("CUST_CR") != null &&
    obj.getChildName().equalsIgnoreCase(txnTypeMap.get("CUST_CR"))) {
    binding.childCardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else  binding.childCardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I hope it will work.